# why I can not use matplotlib and keras at the same time in anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, package

I installed anaconda and I installed Keras and tenserflow by defining a new environment.

`conda create -n keras  python=3.7.6`

`conda activate keras`

`conda install keras`

I wanted to use matplotlib , but I got error that `No module named 'matplotlib`.

So I decided to create and activate it the same as I did for keras above.

But   these packages don't work at the same times! when I load package `keras` and `Tensorflow` in anaconda . it's fine and they work. but when I load `matplotlib` , `keras` and `Tensorflow` are removed from loaded packages. and when I load `keras` and `tensorflow` , `'matplotlib` is removed. this is so odd to me! any idea?

For example I installed `matplotlib` and you can see in this picture `keras` and `tensorflow` are in the non-installed packages in anaconda. Now if I install them `matplotlib` will be in the non-installed list.

[image]

Comment: So far you show us the code where you create an environment and install `keras` to it. But you did not install matplotlib, or did you? Without matplotlib being installed it cannot be imported.

Comment: of course I did. I just didn't repeated codes

Comment: Apparently you created one environment where you installed keras, and another environment where you installed matplotlib. Instead you of course need to install both in the *same* environment.